# The LINQ expression DbSet<>.Any could not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using ConsmoDB and Entity Framework Core 3.1.
Need to check if entity exists

```
bool callExists = await _context.Calls
    .AsNoTracking()
    .AnyAsync(x => x.Number == request.Number && x.CustomerId == request.CustomerId, cancellationToken);

if (callExists)
{
    throw new ConflictException($"Call already exists");
}
```

after run, got the following exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>           .Any(c => c.Number == __request_Number_0 && c.CustomerId  == __request_CustomerId_1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
>   explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
>   AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression
>   translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
>   methodCallExpression)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
>   visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression
>   query)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression
>   query, Boolean async)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase
>   database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object
>   cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression
>   query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression
>   expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo
>   operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo
>   operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, LambdaExpression expression,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AnyAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Call.Api.Handlers.CreateCallCommandHandler.Handle(CreateCallMappingCommand
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\Call.Api\Handlers\CreateCallCommandHandler.cs:line 40
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestExceptionActionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1
>   next)
>          at Call.Api.Controllers.CallsController.Create(CreateCallMappingCommand
>   createCallMappingCommand) in
>   D:\Call.Api\Controllers\CallsController.cs:line 52
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
>   context)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
>   isCompleted)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
>   invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
>   endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>          at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext)
>          at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

Model Call
public class Call

```
{
    public Guid CallId { get; set; }

    public string Number { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }
}
```

Request is the same (only without CallId)

Comment: Can you please add types (entity and request)?

Comment: You might want to try first putting the values from `request` into local variables and using them instead as EF likely doesn't know how to translate the `request` object into SQL.

Comment: As the exception is telling you, there's no translation for linq `.Any()` method when using azure cosmos db entity framework provider.

Comment: Or try moving the filtering to a `Where` followed by a `AsEnumerable` and then `Any`.

Comment: Added entity model

Answer (score 2):

`.AnyAsync` is not supported.  As an alternative you can use `.CountAsync()` and check for `count > 0`;

It boggles the mind that the team would implement `.CountAsync` and not `.AnyAsync`.